# Replace space slash space in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to know how I can replace `" / "` (note the 2 spaces around it) to `|` in JavaScript.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
' / '.replace(/\s\/\s/g, "|");
```

Comment: Damn, the question keeps changing...

Comment: It works with literal spaces, instead of `\s`

Comment: Your code perfectly works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace()` function doesn't work in-place. It generates a new string. Assign the returned value:

```
s1 = ' / '
s2 = s1.replace(/\s\/\s/g, "|");
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace "// ", do this :

```
s = s.replace(/\/\/\s/g, "|");
```

To replace " / ", do this :

```
s = s.replace(/ \/ /g, "|");
```

`\/` is a slash

`\s` is a space

If you want to replace just the standard space, use a standard space, not `\s`

Comment: He doesn't want to replace `"// "`, he wants to replace `" / "`

Comment: @WouterJ The question changed and you know it...

Comment: Ah, ok :) But now you have the same answer in your code as he in the question :)

Comment: @WouterJ Not totally. Just in case of doubt I had added the `s = s.` part.

Comment: btw, @dystroy, I didn't knew the question was changed from `"// "` to `" / "`, since it was done in the time where revisions aren't captured. I only reformatted the question. But I can now see what the starter may does wrong: +1